# How can I open a file with a non-zip extension as a zip file in emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I'd like to be able to open files with extensions other that .zip that have zip contents using Emacs' built-in zip file support.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Shouldn't it be asked at superuser.com?

Comment: I suppose it's possible.  I consider emacs questions to be programming-related, though, like asking a question about Eclipse or Visual Studio.

Comment: That's really a problem for Emacs (and I imagine Eclips/Visual Studio), there's a community here, but not so much on super user...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the file, then type

```
M-: (archive-mode)
```

If you're doing this a lot, then you might want to create a command to do it (because archive-mode isn't a command.  Comments in the function say:

```
;; This is not interactive because you shouldn't be turning this
;; mode on and off.  You can corrupt things that way.
```

But you could easily advise it to make it interactive:

```
(defadvice archive-mode (before archive-mode-interactive activate)
  "Make this interactive"
  (interactive))
```

At which point you can now do `M-x archive-mode`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want a more permanent solution, I do something like this in my .emacs:

```
;; Use archive mode to open Python eggs
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.egg\\'" . archive-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.odp\\'" . archive-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.otp\\'" . archive-mode))
;; also for .xo files (zip)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.xo\\'" . archive-mode))
```

Comment: True that, I didn't read the question closely enough (I missed the whole "other extensions" line.